# Como enviar variáveis de form_tag para função javascript? Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc

Sou novo em programação web e em rails e tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho uma view que exibe uma lista de alimentos e um campo para preencher com a quantidade de gramas que eu quero de cada alimento. Gostaria de exibir um `text_field_tag` para cada elemento da lista que eu possuo, algo como:

```
<% @alimentos.each do |alimento| %>
    <%= text_field_tag :alimento %>
    <%= label_tag(:alimento, "#{alimento.nome}: #{alimento.preco} reais a grama" )%>
<% end %>`
```

Porém, gostaria de enviar a quantidade que colocasse nos campos para uma função javascript que multiplicasse o preço pelo valor que inseri e então exibisse na view o valor total calculado.

Infelizmente não tenho ideia de como fazer isso: Como criar um `text_field_tag` com um símbolo diferente para cada iteração do *each*? Como enviar os valores que preenchem os campos para a função javascript, onde criar a função javascript e como exibir o resultado do cálculo da função?

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao digitar a quantidade há vários eventos que pode disparar o cálculo, você precisa saber quando você quer calcular. Quando ele estiver digitando? Quando clicar fora do text_field? Ao clicar em um botão para calcular? Etc.

Na view você pode passar alguns dados como atributos nas tags e usar o método `each_with_index` para criar cada tag com um id diferente.

```
<% @alimentos.each_with_index do |alimento, i| %>
    <%= text_field_tag :alimento, class: 'quantidade', data-id: i %>
    <%= label_tag(:alimento, "#{alimento.nome}: #{alimento.preco} reais a grama", id: 'total-#{i}', "data-preco": alimento.preco, "data-nome": alimento.nome) %>
<% end %>
```

Então no JavaScript você espera o evento acontecer, calcula e coloca na view pegando os dados dos atributos.

```
//exemplo para cacular quando o foco sair da text_field
$("body").on("focusout", ".quantidade", function() {
  // this será o text_field que saiu do foco
  var id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
  var value = this.value;
  var preco = document.getElementById("total-" + id).getAttribute("data-preco");
  var nome = document.getElementById("total-" + id).getAttribute("data-nome");
  document.getElementById("total-" + id).textContent = nome+": " + (preco*value) +" reais a grama";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem sua pergunta, eu consegui fazer algo parecido utilizando as gems simple_form e cocoon (para nested forms). Esta última gera nomes serializados conforme a quantidade de registros no subform. Assim você poderia fazer algo do tipo na view:

`<td><%= f.input :alimento_quantidade, :input_html => {:onChange =>  customFunction();'} %></td>`

Esta função coffeescript/javascript faria os cálculos e atualizaria um campo de totais.